Remotely map SMB Share to Server via powershell throws confusing error
the following is my szenario:
I maintain/update a lot of my servers with an gitlab CI/CD Powershell Pipeline. I use it to transfer and execute scripts on the remote machine.
The problem I encounter is when I try to connect an SMB Share to the server to transfer data from, I get this error:
A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated
I get this error when I use New-PSDrive and New-SMBMapping.
The setup I use to execute commands on the system:
I "prepare" the system once and create a PSSession to run with credentials of a local admin on that machine.
I then open the pre-configured session and use the Invoke-Command to execute powershell scripts as the local admin.
The way I try to connect the NAS:
The user I need to use to access the NAS is different and not available on the machine itself. I load the credentials first ($credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user, $password), the password is filled in earlier from a previously generated password file).
Then I try to connect to the NAS using this command:
New-PSDrive -Name "N" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Persist -Root $nas -Scope Global -Credential $credentials
This may seem overly complicated, but it works perfectly for everything else the pipeline needs to do. I just now have the special case that I need to connect to a NAS with different credentials. With our other machines, I just access the network path with the executing user, but that doesn't work here sadly.
I already did a lot of research and debugging. The internet tells me it is a double-hop problem, but I don't really see how it could be, because we use the pre-configured PS Session (which is stated as a solution to the double-hop problem).
The really weird thing is, when I execute the script locally, it works fine. It only fails when I let it execute via gitlab and the Invoke-Command.
Maybe some of you have an idea on what to do.
